# How do I retrieve an image for use in a vue file?

Tags: vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js

I have been making a portfolio website, usually when using Nuxt I have an assets folder, this time I did not have one.

Therefore, I created one manually and added my images into it, however, I cannot retrieve the images for use on my vue file.

However, I get the error below:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors 

 This dependency was not found:  

 * ~/assets/ethereum.jpg in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/previousWork.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

 To install it, you can run: npm install --save ~/assets/ethereum.jpg
```

Below is the code found in my "previousWork.vue" file.

```
<template>
<div class="bg-black h-screen px-6 py-12">
    <h2 class="text-white font-exo text-5xl ">
        PREVIOUS WORK
    </h2>
    <div class="flex space-x-2">
        <div v-for="project in projects">
         <img :src="project.image.url" alt="" style="height: 70vh;" class="object-cover">
         <p class="font-space-mono text-white text-sm">{{project.title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import ethereumImg from '~/assets/ethereum.jpg'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            projects: [
                {
                    image: {
                        url: ethereumImg
                        },
                        title: 'ETHEREUM CARBON CALCULATOR'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Below is the code found in my "package.json" file. (dependencies etc)

```
{
  "name": "my-portfolio-nuxt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "dat.gui": "0.7.7",
    "gsap": "3.6.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "orbit-controls-es6": "^2.0.1",
    "three": "^0.126.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^1.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.4"
  }
}
```

Below is the file structure used for this site.
[File Structure in use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Mhr.png)

Comment: Please, clarify if `~` works for other imports

Comment: I have not used it in any other imports, should I have installed any packages prior to using it?

Comment: It should work out of the box if the config wasn't messed up. In the screenshot you posted, there's a typo in ethereum.

Comment: I thank you for your keen eye, clearly mine was not good enough lol, that fixed it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you don't have to import the image as `/assets` contains your un-compiled assets such as Stylus or SASS files, images, or fonts. Inside your vue templates, if you need to link to your assets directory use `~/assets/ethereum.jpg` with a slash before assets.

```html
<template>
  <img src="~/assets/ethereum.jpg" />
</template>
```

Inside your css files, if you need to reference your  assets  directory, use `~assets/your_image.png` **(without a slash)**

```css
background: url('~assets/ethereum.jpg');
```

As you are using Nuxt I would suggest putting the image files inside `/static`. The static directory is directly mapped to the server root () and contains files that likely won't be changed. All included files will be automatically served by Nuxt and are accessible through your project root URL.

```html
<!-- Static image from static directory -->
<img src="/ethereum.jpg" />

<!-- webpacked image from assets directory -->
<img src="~/assets/ethereum.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this comment by Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338841/how-do-i-retrieve-an-image-for-use-in-a-vue-file#comment127796376_72338841), the issue was mainly a typo in the name of the file, `etheruem` rather than `ethereum`. That fixed the issue.